# Facebook connections using C language

Tags: c, facebook, c++11

Can someone tell me how can I connect to my "facebook" account using only the C standard library?

What I want is something like:

```
#include<sys/socket.h>
```

Comment: I think you might use libcurl! Is not so simple to interface C with the web! :)  http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/

Comment: Facebook supplies an API for app developers, might want to start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform).  Note that you're going to want to use something a bit higher-level than raw sockets for connecting (something like libcurl as Sergio mentions above).

Comment: Folly: Facebook Open-source Library  https://github.com/facebook/folly  you may read this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect ?
Well libcurl is easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library, supporting DICT, FILE, FTP, FTPS, Gopher, HTTP, HTTPS, IMAP, IMAPS, LDAP, LDAPS, POP3, POP3S, RTMP, RTSP, SCP, SFTP, SMTP, SMTPS, Telnet and TFTP. libcurl supports SSL certificates, HTTP POST, HTTP PUT, FTP uploading, HTTP form based upload, proxies, cookies, user+password authentication (Basic, Digest, NTLM, Negotiate, Kerberos), file transfer resume, http proxy tunneling and more!  But you need deep knowldege if using libcurl. You can download webpage. Libcurl handles application level protocols, so you don't have to write your own HTTP client code (for example) , now it's up to you.